# Find boundary of flex graphic object?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, drawing, graphic, boundary

I have a set of shapes created using flex graphic object. I need to draw line connecting them, for which i need to find the boundary of these shapes. I want only the content area, not the transparent part. is there any solution for this?

Comment: Show some code, perhaps a screenshot of what you currently have and what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BitmapData.getColorBoundRect()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getColorBoundsRect%28%29) with the color set to transparent (0x00000000) and findColor set to false.

Comment: A point is just a geometric object defining x and y coordinates. It wouldn't have any BitmapData. However, I suspect you have _something_ on the Display List you are calling a point, and you can probably get its BitmapData by creating a new BitmapData and using draw() to draw its pixels. Remember to add the x and y coordinates of the original Display object to the rect you get.